# Excel VBA connect to SQL Server Login Error

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am a beginner in Excel VBA and faced a problem: I can connect to remote SQL Server through Management Studio, but got error when connecting through Excel VBA.

Below is my connection string and the error code.

```
Const connection_string As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=RPGTFDB;Data Source=122.xxx.xxx.xxx;User ID=sa;Password=xxx"
```

Error is:

> Run-time error (80004005): Login failed for user ". The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

Is it not able to get the User ID?

However when I connect to local computer, like 127.0.0.1, the above connection string works.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string you should not use

```
User ID=sa;Password=xxx
```

As the error seems to be indicating that only Windows Logins are enabled on the SQL Server and this connection string item is only for SQL Logins.

Comment: Hi RBarry, I have set the SQL server to enable both SQL Login and Windows Authentication. As the Excel gotta be used on many computers, SQL login has to be used. Please advice! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to punch in a login and password when connecting with management studio? If not then I suggest you have a database that authenticates a connection using your windows login.

If this is the case, then remove the User ID and Password bits and insert Trusted_Connection=Yes instead.

Comment: Hi Bathsheba and RBarry, Yes I punched in login and password when connecting with management studio and it works. Because the Excel VBA program is going to be used on different computers, hence I need to setup using SQL login. Please advice what should I do! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the connection string is created using UDL application. 
Despite I still cannot find any difference between the string and the manual created one, it works!

Follow the instructions in this link:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1409.how-to-create-a-sql-connection-string-for-an-application-udl-file.aspx